# Call nuxt/axios module from external js/ts file

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I am new to vue and trying to build my first vue app using nuxtjs.  My problem right now has to do with architecture and folder structure.

In my other non-vue apps I always have a "services" directory where I keep all my code that makes http requests.

example under my services folder I will have a auth.ts file that contains code that posts login credentials to my API. This file/class returns a promise which I access from within my store.

I am trying to do this with vue using nuxtjs but I realised I am unable to access the axios module from anywhere aside my .vue file.

This is an example of how my code is now:

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import ActionBar from '../../components/ActionBar.vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  components: { ActionBar },
  data() {
    return {
      example: ''
  },
  methods: {},
  mounted() {
    this.$axios.$get('/examples').then((res) => {
      this.examples = res.data;
    })
  }
})
</script>

<style>
...
</style>
```

I would like to move the axios calls to their own files in my services folder.  How do I do this?

Comment: you can have the same "utilities" folder, and call it, but I would suggest the use of the `store` to actually call external methods... [check how stores work](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/) and you will see it's even easier than you though   I would also suggest to go through a [NuxtJs course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltzlhAxJr74), just so you familiarize with the hole process... I love it youtube

Comment: Alright but how do I access the $axios module from my store?

Comment: remember you can always do `import axios from 'axios'` but in case of axios, as it's an injected package, you can simply do `this.$axios`

Comment: Yes that's my problem. this.$axios only seems to work from .vue files.

Comment: no, it's injected in the store, remember store files are Vuex stores, so they all have `this.$axios`, a simple `Object.keys(this)` will show all keys you can use, here's an example of [one of my store file](https://pastebin.com/Me8pRvH3) the actions calls

Comment: Thank you, will try that. :)

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is create a file inside the `./store` folder, let's imagine, `./store/products.js`, that will create a products store, inside, simple getters, mutations and actions:

```js
export const state = () => ({
    products: [],
    fetchingProducts: false,
})

export const getters = {
    getAllProducts(state) {
        return state.products
    },
    hasProducts(state) {
        return state.products.length > 0
    },
    isFetchingProducts(state) {
        return state.fetchingProducts
    },
}

export const mutations = {
    setInitialData(state, products) {
        state.products = products
    },
    setLoadingProducts(state, isLoading) {
        state.fetchingProducts = isLoading
    },
}


export const actions = {
    async fetchProducts(context, payload) {
        context.commit('setLoadingProducts', true)

        const url = `/api/example/${payload.something}`
        const res = await this.$axios.get(url)
        context.commit('setInitialData', res.data)
        context.commit('setLoadingProducts', false)
    },
}
```

then in your `.vue` file, you can now use the store as:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="isFetchingProducts"> loading... </div>
    <div v-else-if="!hasProducts">no products found</div>
    <div v-else>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="product in allProducts" :key="product.id">
          {{ product.name }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        products: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapGetters({
        isFetchingProducts: 'products/isFetchingProducts',
        allProducts: 'products/getAllProducts',
        hasProducts: 'products/hasProducts',
      })
    },
    mounted() {
      this.$store.dispatch('products/fetchProducts', {})
    },
  }
</script>

<style>
...
</style>
```

remember that:

- to call a store action, you should use `$store.dispatch()`
- to call a mutation, you should use `$store.commit()`
- to call a getter, you should use `$store.getter()`

you can also use the Vuex helper [`mapGetters`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper), [`mapActions`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions-in-components) and even [`mapMutations`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#committing-mutations-in-components)

---

You might also know that you can leverage [the Plugins](https://blog.lichter.io/posts/nuxt-api-call-organization-and-decoupling/) in Nuxt, that article has [demo code](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/manniL/nuxt-decouple-and-organize-api-calls) as well so you can follow up really quick